# Java : Merging two sorted linked lists

Tags: java, algorithm, merge, linked-list

I have developed a code to merge two already sorted linked lists in java.

I need help with the following:

1. How do I retain the value of head node of merged list without using tempNode?
2. Can this code be better optimized?

   ```
   public static ListNode mergeSortedListIteration(ListNode nodeA, ListNode nodeB) {
      ListNode mergedNode ;
      ListNode tempNode ;      

   if (nodeA == null) {
       return nodeB;
     } 
     if (nodeB == null) {
       return nodeA;
     }     


   if ( nodeA.getValue() < nodeB.getValue())
   {
       mergedNode = nodeA;
       nodeA = nodeA.getNext();
   }
   else
   {
       mergedNode = nodeB;
       nodeB = nodeB.getNext();
   }

   tempNode = mergedNode; 

   while (nodeA != null && nodeB != null)
   {           

       if ( nodeA.getValue() < nodeB.getValue())
       {               
           mergedNode.setNext(nodeA);
           nodeA = nodeA.getNext();
       }
       else
       {
           mergedNode.setNext(nodeB);
           nodeB = nodeB.getNext();                
       }       
       mergedNode = mergedNode.getNext();
   }

   if (nodeA != null)
   {
       mergedNode.setNext(nodeA);
   }

   if (nodeB != null)
   {
       mergedNode.setNext(nodeB);
   }       
   return tempNode;
   }
   ```

Comment: Is this homework? If so, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: No, this is not a homework. thanks.

Comment: Then why aren't you using the Collections API? Just iterate over the first list, comparing and inserting items from the second list as appropriate using `ListIterator.add()`.

Comment: I am writing my own algorithm for this. So cant use collections API.

Comment: Well... yes, you can. I just described the algorithm in my last comment, and it would be easier to write (and easier for other folks down the road to understand) using the existing classes. Just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: You have to keep a record of the first node, which means you will have to store it in a variable such as `tempNode`.

2: No. There's not much to optimize here. The process is quite trivial.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possibilities:

1) Instead of using `mergedNode` to keep track of the previous node, use `nodeA.getNext().getValue()` and `nodeB.getNext().getValue()`.  Your algorithm will become more complex and you will have to deal with a few edge cases, but it is possible to eliminate one of your variables.

2) Use a doubly linked-list, and then use either `nodeA.getPrev().getValue()` and `nodeB.getPrev().getValue()` instead of `mergedNode`.  You will also have to deal with edge cases here too.

In order to deal with edge cases, you will have to guarantee that your references can not possibly be `null` before calling `getPrev()`, `getNext()` or `getValue()`, or else you will throw an exception.

Note that the above modifications sacrifice execution time slightly and (more importantly) simplicity in order to eliminate a variable.  Any gains would be marginal, and developer time is far more important than shaving a microsecond or two off of your operation.